# Will this android rom work for hd7?

Tags: custom-roms, rom

Will this hd2 rom work on the hd7 since they have almost the same hardware?

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1930240

Answer (score 2):

I would NOT RECOMMEND using a ROM that was not built to go with your specific device. If you use a ROM that doesn't go with your device, even if the ROM goes with your device on a different carrier, you risk bricking the device. Make sure that your device specs match EXACTLY to the ROM specs.

Rule of thumb when it comes to ROMs:

> close only counts in horseshoes and hand grenades.

Comment: As long as the radio image is left untouched, unbricking should be possible. But you're correct: it saves a lot of trouble sticking to "exact matches" instead of trying "close misses". However, if one is willing to risk some trouble, and no trouble comes -- that information might be useful to others :D

Comment: John is right, you're safer avoiding it. But you might want to ask this question over on XDA, where you're more likely to find someone crazy enough to have tried it. If it does turn out to be possible, feel free to answer your own question.